# jQuery ajaxStart не вызывался для одного из событий

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть такая проблема: я редактирую чужой скрипт, и там ajaxStart и ajaxStop жестко привязаны к скрипту и мне надо на странице выполнить свой ajax запрос так, что бы не вызывались эти события.
Вопрос: можно ли это как то указать дополнительно в методе ajax (post)? Или возможно исправить что сочинил автор.
В интернете ответа, к сожалению, не нашел..

Вот как у автора обрабатывается этот метод (без него не работает его скрипт():

```
jQuery(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    console.log('ajaxStart');
});
```

Для метода ajaxStop аналогично.

Comment: и как же это вам помешал вывод текстового сообщения в консоль о том, что аякс стартует?

Comment: MasterAlex, Я сократил код автора до минимума, он не столь важен. Пробовал изменить код автора на такой `jQuery('#container').ajaxStart(function () {
        console.log('ajaxStart');
    });`, но все равно отрабатывает и для моего ajax запроса.

Comment: Если он не важен то чем он вам мешает :) Дописывать свой код в эти функции, в смысле `ajaxStart` можете?

Comment: @Firsim, вы пишите что у вас проблема с этим кодом и без него скрипт не работает, но при этом считаете что этот код не важен :)

Comment: @MasterAlex, Просто так и есть) Сложно объяснить.. Просто для того, что бы был этот код важен для просмотра нужно выкладывать весь модуль) А это уже лишняя информация. Спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вообще читайте документацию.

`If $.ajax() or $.ajaxSetup() is called with the global option set to false, the .ajaxStop() method will not fire.`,

`If $.ajax() or $.ajaxSetup() is called with the global option set to false, the .ajaxStart() method will not fire.`

Делайте свой запрос через `$.ajax()` с параметром `global = false`.

Comment: Спасибо, что то гуглом не наткнулся на это.. `$.ajaxSetup({
   global: false
  });`